# Finding solution to quasi-convex problem using CVXPY

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I am trying to solve an optimization problem in Python using the CVXPY package (with the ECOS solver). The problem involves minimizing a linear variable subject to multiple constraints. The problem itself is quasi-convex, so I implement a bisection algorithm to find the optimal solution.

The problem is that the solver always fails when the bisection is getting closer and closer to the optimal value. It's like the solver doesn't know what to do when the solution is approaching the optimal. I believe this problem is related to a tolerance issue, but I'm not sure what tolerance variable to change.

I have tried coding this problem in Python 3.6. I have also tried using different solvers, but the solver always fails when approaching the optimal. The code is shown below. Note that 'gamma' is the variable I am minimizing here.

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

Ts = 500e-6;
w = np.logspace(-1, np.log10(np.pi/Ts), 400);
R = 0.1; L = 4e-2; a = R/L;
G = 0.0125/(np.exp(1j*w*Ts) - np.exp(-a*Ts))

bw = 200; zeta = 0.8;
wn = (2*np.pi*bw)/np.sqrt(1 - 2*np.power(zeta,2) + np.sqrt(2 - 4*np.power(zeta,2) + 4*np.power(zeta,4)))
Td = np.power(wn,2)/(-np.power(w,2) + 2*zeta*wn*1j*w + np.power(wn,2)); Wd = 1/(1-Td);

n = 5
rho_r = cp.Variable(n); rho_s = cp.Variable(n-1); rho_t = cp.Variable(n);

Ro = 0; 
for i in range(n):
    Ri = rho_r[i]*np.exp(-i*1j*w*Ts); 
    Ro = Ro + Ri;

So = 0
for i in range(n-1):
    Si = rho_s[i]*np.exp(-(i+1)*1j*w*Ts); 
    So = So + Si;

So_no_int = 1+So
So = cp.multiply((1-np.exp(-1j*w*Ts)),(1+So));

To = 0; 
for i in range(n):
    Ti = rho_t[i]*np.exp(-i*1j*w*Ts); 
    To = To + Ti;

g_max = 2; g_min = 1e-8; g_tol = 1e-5; gamma = (g_max + g_min)/2; 
mm = 0.5;

while g_max - g_min > g_tol:

    PSI = So + cp.multiply(G,Ro)
    F1 = cp.multiply(cp.inv_pos(gamma),cp.abs(cp.multiply(Wd,PSI - cp.multiply(G,To)))) - cp.real(PSI)
    F2 = cp.abs(cp.multiply(mm,So)) - cp.real(PSI)


    constraints = [F1 <= -1e-6, F2 <= -1e-6, cp.real(So_no_int) >= 5e-3]
    prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(0),constraints)
    prob.solve(solver = cp.ECOS,feastol_inacc = 1e-7)
    stat = prob.status

    if stat == "optimal":
        print("Feasible (gamma = ", gamma ,")")
        gamma_opt = gamma;
        rho_r_OPT = rho_r.value;
        rho_s_OPT = rho_s.value;
        rho_t_OPT = rho_t.value;
        g_max = gamma;
        gamma = np.average([gamma,g_min]);
        GAIN = np.sum(rho_t_OPT)/np.sum(rho_r_OPT);

    else:
        print("Infeasible (gamma = ", gamma ,")")
        g_min = gamma;
        gamma = np.average([gamma,g_max]);


print("\nThe optimal solution gamma = %f" % gamma_opt)
```

Here is the output. You can see that the solution is converging to something close to 1.059....but then the solver runs into an error.

```
Infeasible (gamma =  1.000000005 )
Feasible (gamma =  1.5000000025 )
Feasible (gamma =  1.2500000037499999 )
Feasible (gamma =  1.125000004375 )
Feasible (gamma =  1.0625000046875 )
Infeasible (gamma =  1.0312500048437498 )
Infeasible (gamma =  1.0468750047656248 )
Infeasible (gamma =  1.0546875047265623 )
Infeasible (gamma =  1.0585937547070312 )
Feasible (gamma =  1.0605468796972657 )
Feasible (gamma =  1.0595703172021484 )
Infeasible (gamma =  1.0590820359545898 )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:\Google Drive\...
Stuff\...\Python_Controller_optimization\main_no_LMIs.py", line 60, in <module>
    prob.solve(solver = cp.ECOS,feastol_inacc = 1e-7)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 289, in solve
    return solve_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 574, in _solve
    self.unpack_results(solution, full_chain, inverse_data)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\cvxpy\problems\problem.py", line 717, in unpack_results
    "Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more "
cvxpy.error.SolverError: Solver 'ECOS' failed. Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more information.
[Finished in 4.8s]
```

Here is the result of the last bisection iteration with `verbose = True`:

```
ECOS 2.0.7 - (C) embotech GmbH, Zurich Switzerland, 2012-15. Web: 
www.embotech.com/ECOS
```

````
It     pcost       dcost      gap   pres   dres    k/t    mu     step   sigma     IR    |   BT
 0  +0.000e+00  -6.380e+02  +3e+03  1e-02  1e+01  1e+00  2e+00    ---    ---    1  0  - |  -  - 
 1  +0.000e+00  -1.145e+02  +8e+02  4e-04  4e+00  1e+00  4e-01  0.8673  1e-01   1  1  1 |  0  0
 2  +0.000e+00  -7.961e+01  +4e+02  3e-04  2e+00  6e-01  2e-01  0.7724  4e-01   2  1  2 |  0  0
 3  +0.000e+00  -3.442e+01  +2e+02  1e-04  8e-01  2e-01  9e-02  0.6591  2e-01   2  1  2 |  0  0
 4  +0.000e+00  -1.446e+01  +1e+02  6e-05  2e-01  5e-02  5e-02  0.7673  4e-01   2  2  2 |  0  0
 5  +0.000e+00  -1.551e+00  +1e+01  6e-06  2e-02  4e-03  5e-03  0.8955  2e-02   2  1  1 |  0  0
 6  +0.000e+00  -7.516e-01  +5e+00  3e-06  1e-02  1e-03  3e-03  0.7389  3e-01   2  2  2 |  0  0
 7  +0.000e+00  -2.738e-01  +2e+00  1e-06  3e-03  5e-04  1e-03  0.7857  2e-01   3  3  3 |  0  0
 8  +0.000e+00  -1.707e-01  +1e+00  7e-07  1e-03  3e-04  6e-04  0.7419  5e-01   3  3  3 |  0  0
 9  +0.000e+00  -3.000e-02  +2e-01  1e-07  2e-04  4e-05  1e-04  0.8592  4e-02   2  3  3 |  0  0
10  +0.000e+00  -2.762e-02  +2e-01  1e-07  1e-04  4e-05  1e-04  0.1937  6e-01   3  3  4 |  0  0
11  +0.000e+00  -1.464e-02  +1e-01  6e-08  4e-05  2e-05  6e-05  0.6035  2e-01   3  4  4 |  0  0
12  +0.000e+00  -1.150e-02  +1e-01  5e-08  1e-05  2e-05  5e-05  0.5393  6e-01   3  4  4 |  0  0
13  +0.000e+00  -8.110e-03  +1e-01  3e-08  5e-06  1e-05  5e-05  0.4090  3e-01   4  5  5 |  0  0
14  +0.000e+00  -4.994e-03  +9e-02  2e-08  2e-06  8e-06  5e-05  0.5449  3e-01   5  6  6 |  0  0
15  +0.000e+00  -4.390e-03  +1e-01  2e-08  2e-06  8e-06  5e-05  0.2976  6e-01   5  6  6 |  0  0
16  +0.000e+00  -1.789e-03  +6e-02  8e-09  5e-07  4e-06  3e-05  0.6651  1e-01   4  5  5 |  0  0
17  +0.000e+00  -9.008e-04  +4e-02  5e-09  2e-07  2e-06  2e-05  0.5673  1e-01   5  6  6 |  0  0
18  +0.000e+00  -6.047e-05  +9e-03  3e-09  1e-08  4e-07  4e-06  0.9890  6e-02   5  5  6 |  0  0
19  +0.000e+00  -1.067e-05  +3e-03  3e-09  4e-09  3e-07  1e-06  0.9708  2e-01   5  6  6 |  0  0
20  +0.000e+00  -8.619e-07  +3e-04  3e-09  4e-09  3e-08  2e-07  0.9503  3e-02   6  6  6 |  0  0
21  +0.000e+00  -1.358e-07  +6e-05  3e-09  4e-09  6e-09  3e-08  0.8718  3e-02   6  5  6 |  0  0
22  +0.000e+00  -1.090e-07  +5e-05  3e-09  4e-09  7e-09  3e-08  0.4582  6e-01   5  5  5 |  0  0
23  +0.000e+00  -3.494e-08  +2e-05  3e-09  4e-09  4e-09  1e-08  0.8998  2e-01   7  5  5 |  0  0
24  +0.000e+00  -2.603e-08  +2e-05  3e-09  4e-09  3e-09  9e-09  0.5242  5e-01   7  5  5 |  0  0
25  +0.000e+00  -2.509e-08  +2e-05  3e-09  4e-09  3e-09  9e-09  0.1730  8e-01   7  5  5 |  0  0
26  +0.000e+00  -1.781e-08  +1e-05  3e-09  4e-09  3e-09  7e-09  0.4828  4e-01   5  5  5 |  0  0
27  +0.000e+00  -1.782e-08  +1e-05  3e-09  4e-09  3e-09  7e-09  0.0071  1e+00   6  5  5 |  0  0
28  +0.000e+00  -7.540e-09  +6e-06  3e-09  4e-09  2e-09  3e-09  0.9672  4e-01   5  5  6 |  0  0
29  +0.000e+00  -7.547e-09  +6e-06  3e-09  4e-09  2e-09  3e-09  0.0134  9e-01   5  5  5 |  0  0
30  +0.000e+00  -7.557e-09  +8e-06  1e-05  4e-09  2e-09  4e-09  0.1284  1e+00   0  4  6 |  0  0
Unreliable search direction detected, recovering best iterate (18) and stopping.

NUMERICAL PROBLEMS (reached feastol=1.1e-08, reltol=-nan(ind), abstol=8.9e-03).
Runtime: 0.182235 seconds.```
````

Comment: Do you get more information by solving with `verbose=True` as suggested?

Comment: Yes. I will edit my post with the result from verbose = True. Thanks.

Comment: For what it’s worth: CVXPY now supports quasiconvex programming. If your problem is DQCP compliant, it will try to solve it if you call ‘prob.solve(qcp=True)’. See https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/dqcp/index.html

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried that, and the solver reported that my problem was not DQCP...But I know that it is (proved mathematically). So I think that the bisection way remains the most reliable.

Comment: I notice that when I set ```abstol_inacc = 1e-2``` in ```prob.solve()```, the problem is fixed. But is it dangerous to put such a large value for this tolerance? On the ECOS documentation, it states that ```abstol_inacc```: the absolute tolerance on the duality gap if reduced precision, default 5e-5 (or absolute accuracy for inaccurate solution).

Comment: If you're an academic, MOSEK is free to use. It's the most reliable general purpose convex solver.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be here:

```
cp.multiply(cp.inv_pos(gamma),cp.abs(cp.multiply(Wd,PSI - cp.multiply(G,To)))) - cp.real(PSI)
```

`cp.inv_pos(gamma)` is a convex, non-negative function and so is `cp.abs(...)`.

Scalar products are quasiconcave when their arguments are non-negative, as is the case here. But to satisfy quasiconcavity, both of the inputs must be concave. Since the inputs are convex, the curvature is not known. Therefore, the problem itself is non-convex. (See [here](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/dqcp/index.html).)